# Making a hashmap with multiple tokens

Tags: java

I have the following text file

```
0 name1 name2 name3 name4 vs. name11 name22 name33 name44
1 name1 name2 name3 name4 vs. name11 name22 name33 name44
```

I want to store `0, name1 through 4 and name11 through name44`.

The program I am making tells me which team won.
If the first integer is 0 then name11 through name44 won and vice versa

I am stuck on how to make multiple tokens?

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Winning {

    public static int whoWon(String filename) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            String line = "";
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                String parts[] = line.split(" ");
                map.put(parts[0], parts[1]);
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(map.toString());

        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stats s = new Stats();
        s.wins("filepath/filename.txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A map can, of course, store a Collection as the value, so you could do something like this...

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
...
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add(parts[1]);
...add all tokens to list
map.put(parts[0], list);
```

Comment: I understand that storing them would get me all values with 0 and 1. But how can I split them again too check which team one?  Because I will get a list of all people with 1 and 0. If its a 0 in the starting, the team after vs won.

Comment: Ah, misread that. Ok, then you could, either split by "vs\\.", for example, or, more easily, iterate (with a for loop) through elements 1-4 of your array (from split) if the number is 0 or through 6-9 if the number is 1 and only add these to the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Map<String, List<String>> map` or  `Map<String, String[]> map`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to make a dto as `Team` in which you can store team details like team members name.

Then you can make another dto as `Match` in which you can store team1, team2 and a boolean of which team won.

And then you can create a `list` of `Match` in which you can put your each line of text file.

**If the first integer is 0 then name11 through name44 won and vice versa**, so I guess you will have multiple lines having value as 0 as well as 1.

So I don't see a use-case of Map in your case.